# Why my iOS app is not compatible with old devices(e.g. iPhone 4S, 5, iPad 2)?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, compatibility

I created app with xcode and selected universal as device and deployment target is iOS 8.0.

I sent my app to App Store and approved but I see that list at app page.

> Requires iOS 8.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, iPhone
>   6 Plus, iPhone 6s, iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone SE, iPad Air, iPad Air Wi-Fi
>   + Cellular, iPad mini 2, iPad mini 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad Air 2, iPad Air 2 Wi-Fi + Cellular, iPad mini 3, iPad mini 3 Wi-Fi +
>   Cellular, iPad mini 4, iPad mini 4 Wi-Fi + Cellular, 12.9-inch iPad
>   Pro, 12.9-inch iPad Pro Wi-Fi + Cellular, 9.7-inch iPad Pro, 9.7-inch
>   iPad Pro Wi-Fi + Cellular, and iPod touch (6th generation).

I need to support iPad 2, iPad 3, iPad 4 and iPhone 4S and iPhone 5. What can i do ?

Comment: Perhaps you created a 64-bit only application?

Comment: armv7 is listes as valid architecture at build settings.

Comment: See @Summer's comment, if arm64 is listed in "required architecture", it doesn't matter if armv7 is listed as valid. Are you able to post any screenshots of your project settings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check *Build Settings -> Architecture*. Make sure you include `armv7` as a valid architecture.

Also try to add the app preview screen shots that fit iPhone 5 screen size (320*568) to iTunes Connect.

**Edit**

I've double checked my app in the App Store. The app capability is described as "*Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.*"

I'd suggest you ensure the "Device Requirements" section in iTunes Connect is correct. To do this, check "Activity -> iOS Builds -> Version X.X -> Device Requirements". My setting here is as following (No ipad support):

[image]

The most important part is to check "Required Capabilities" section does not include "arm64". Based on this [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1910/_index.html):

> In order to be eligible for installation on the devices listed at the
>   beginning of this document, your application must be compiled for
>   armv7 (in addition to arm64) and must not include the arm64 required
>   device capability.

You can find a solution at section "Remove the arm64 required device capability" in the same [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1910/_index.html).

The last resort: File a technical support specifically for your app capability issue to Apple from your developer portal.

Comment: Hello, I already uploaded 3.5" screenshots to itunes already olso this is my settings: https://s31.postimg.org/k969oi36z/Screen_Shot_2016_07_26_at_20_45_47.png

Comment: @mTuran I've add some more information about the possible solution to my answer. Is your capability setting at the iTunes Connect same as mine?

Answer (score 2):

Those list of devices you've mentioned , are 64bit devices. Probably you're only compiling for 64bit devices. This mistake could happen if you're debugging using a 64bit device.

Under the build settings, there's this field

```
Build Active Architectures Only
```

Make sure to set **NO** for `Release` and **YES** for `Debug`

And also make sure you have all these : `arm64 armv7 armv7s` under `Valid Architectures` field.

Answer (score 2):

See @Summer's comment, if arm64 is listed in "required architecture", it doesn't matter if armv7 is listed as valid.

Also, please note that sometimes settings in your specific target can override settings in your project.

Here are screenshots of where I would look:

In your info.plist:
[image: In your info.plist]

In your project settings:
[image: In your project settings]

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have anything requiring a 64 bit system under the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the build on old Xcode like Xcode 6.0 and try to install the build in iPhone 5 and iPad2? See if this helps you.