# iOS App won't install on older devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, compatibility

I've got an app on the iOS App Store, it installs fine on devices such as an iPhone 6S, an iPad Air, and iPad Pro etc, however it does not install on an iPad 3 or iPad 4, instead it shows an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt7ol.png) "This app is not compatible with your device". The deployment target of the app is iOS 8, and both the iPads are running iOS 9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my iOS app is not compatible with old devices(e.g. iPhone 4S, 5, iPad 2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593918/why-my-ios-app-is-not-compatible-with-old-devicese-g-iphone-4s-5-ipad-2)

Answer (score 0):

Check your architectures list, which is located at "Build Settings" tab of your target. It should include not only arm64 but also armv7.